Cyrillic letter Tje with breve appears in 1951 engraving
I am reading an engraving published in 1951 by the Broude Brothers. It contains a weird thing shaped like the letter Tje with a breve (Ᲊ̆):

What exactly is it? And what is it called? The letter Tje is not used in Russian, so even Russians (I'm not Russian) won't know it.
The "duplicate" is actually the pronunciation of ye and yat, whereas my post is about tje.

For the lols, this engraving is a score of Swan Lake. Ᲊ̆, marked in red, appears in the description of the second scene of Act I (Tchaikovsky's original version).

This is an obsolete letter "ять": wikipedia.
You can pronounce it as "e".

Why is yat written as tje with breve?

It's not like the Serbian letter tje with a breve. The Serbian letter ћ is written like an "h" with a bar. Yat' is written like a Russian soft sign with a bar. ћ is pronounced /tɕ/ - I believe it derives from ть; whereas the Serbian ч is /ʈ͡ʂ/. None of this has anything to do with the letter yat'.

@Pierre2001: that's no breve, that's a cupped adnate serif over the vertical bar
